# Excel VB for loop; how do you specify that the parameter i is a parameter in the code?

Tags: microsoft-excel

When you do a for loop in Excel VB, how do you specify that the parameter is a number in the code.  More especifically, suppose I want to open 500 files, named as file1, file2, file3, ...
how do you specify in the following code that "i" is a number, not a letter???

```
Sub CopyCells()
    For i = 1 To 500
        Workbooks.Open Filename:="filei.do"
    Next i
End Sub
```

I don´t know any Excel VB; I know how to program in Stata much better.  My problem is that I have 500 excel files that I have to format and save before I can export to Stata without problem.  To do that, I wrote a VB code.  All is working well, except a for loop, because I don´t know how to say that "i" is a number, not the letter i.  In Stata all you do is to write `i'.

Answer (score 3):

You would need to convert the variable `i` from a integer type to a string type first, using the `CStr` function should do the job:-

```
Sub CopyCells()
    For i = 1 To 500
        Workbooks.Open Filename:="file" + CStr(i) + ".do"
    Next i
End Sub
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ch47ss2a(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: or use string concatenation operators with implicit conversion `"file" & i & ".do"`